# ending a do-while loop

Tags: java, do-while

Ok I have a do-while loop that's supposed to end when the use hits 'q' but it is giving me the error message instead please help.

```
package Assignments;
import java.util.*;
public class assignment3 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Scanner
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Variables
        final double METERS_TO_CM = 100;   // The constant to convert meters to centimeters
        final double BSA_CONSTANT = 3600;  // The constant to divide by for bsa
        double bmi;                        // Body Mass Index
        double weight;                     // Weight in kilograms
        double height;                     // Height in meters
        String classification;             // Classifies the user into BMI categories 
        double bsa;                        // Body surface area



        System.out.print("Welcome to the BMI and BSA Calculator to begin enter weight in kilograms.");
        weight = stdIn.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter height in meters: ");
        height = stdIn.nextDouble();
        bmi = weight/(height*height);       // Calculates BMI
        bsa = Math.sqrt(((height*METERS_TO_CM)*weight)/BSA_CONSTANT);    // Calculates BSA


        if (bmi < 18.5)
        {
            classification = "Underweight";
        }
        else if (bmi < 25)
        {
            classification = "Normal";
        }
        else if (bmi < 30)
        {
            classification = "Overweight";
        }
        else
        {
            classification = "Obese";
        }
        System.out.println("Choose Options below to set height and weight");
        System.out.println("Your classification is: " + classification);
        System.out.println("(H)eight: " + height + " meters");
        System.out.println("(W)eight: " + weight + " kilograms");
        System.out.printf("BMI: %.1f\n", bmi);
        System.out.printf("BSA: %.2f\n", bsa);
        System.out.println("(Q)uit");
        String response = stdIn.next();

        do {

            if (response.charAt(0)== 'w') 
            {
                System.out.println("Enter new weight: ");
                weight = stdIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Choose Options below to set height and weight");
                System.out.println("Your classification is: " + classification);
                System.out.println("(H)eight: " + height + " meters");
                System.out.println("(W)eight: " + weight + " kilograms");
                System.out.printf("BMI: %.1f\n", bmi);
                System.out.printf("BSA: %.2f\n", bsa);
                System.out.println("(Q)uit");
                bmi = weight/(height*height);       
                bsa = Math.sqrt(((height*METERS_TO_CM)*weight)/BSA_CONSTANT);
                response = stdIn.next();
            }
            else if (response.charAt(0) == 'h')
            {
                System.out.println("Enter new height: ");
                height = stdIn.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Choose Options below to set height and weight");
                System.out.println("Your classification is: " + classification);
                System.out.println("(H)eight: " + height + " meters");
                System.out.println("(W)eight: " + weight + " kilograms");
                System.out.printf("BMI: %.1f\n", bmi);
                System.out.printf("BSA: %.2f\n", bsa);
                System.out.println("(Q)uit");
                bmi = weight/(height*height);       
                bsa = Math.sqrt(((height*METERS_TO_CM)*weight)/BSA_CONSTANT);
                response = stdIn.next();
            }
            else if (response.charAt(0)!= 'w')
            {
                System.out.println("That is not a valid choice try again");
                response = stdIn.next();
            }

            else if (response.charAt(0)!= 'h')
            {
                System.out.println("that is not a valid choise try again");
                response = stdIn.next();
            }
            else if (response.charAt(0) == 'q')
            {
                break;
            }
        } while (response != "q");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error message? also, you should use `!"q".equals(response)` rather than == for String comparison

Comment: there's no error but when I enter q it just gives me the System.out.println("that is not a valid choice try again");
instead of breaking the loop

Comment: And, you should factor out some smaller methods rather than have all that logic in the midst of a big loop -- it will help you reason more carefully about the control flow.

Comment: Your problem is caused by what @David mentioned.  Use `.equals()`.

Comment: All your code is in a single function and could benefit from some refactoring. You have some large blocks of code that could be extracted into separate functions to make the main logic easier to follow. Also, this feels like homework. If so, please mark it as such.

Comment: Consider use of an enumeration for the classification variable, rather than a string...

Answer (score 3):

`q` is not equal to either `w` or `h`. So, condition is true for `else if (response.charAt(0)!= 'w')` and so you aren't going to actual `else if (response.charAt(0) == 'q')` condition to break.

So, place your last 3 `else if` in this fashion -

```
    else if (response.charAt(0) == 'q')
    {
            break;
    }
    else if (response.charAt(0)!= 'w')
    {
            System.out.println("That is not a valid choice try again");
            response = stdIn.next();
    }

    else if (response.charAt(0)!= 'h')
    {
            System.out.println("that is not a valid choise try again");
            response = stdIn.next();
    }
```

Comment: Also, consider clubbing the last two `else-if` in to a single condition like else if (`response.charAt(0)!= 'w' || response.charAt(0)!= 'h')`. Also understand that, in else-if, if one statement is executed, the rest of else-if don't execute.

Comment: @Brad: Consider using a single else block for displaying invalid choice message.

Comment: @Babar - Well, when the body of both `else-if` is same, I don't see any wrong in clubbing those two `else-if` into a single `else-if`. Any valid reason for bad choice.

Comment: @Mahesh: It is fine. But in the context of the choices being selected and individually handled, using an else { } block for displaying 'invalid choice' makes the code more simpler. Consider having 10 or 20 choices and one else-if block with '!=' checks for every option!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is these lines:

```
else if (response.charAt(0)!= 'w')
// ...
else if (response.charAt(0)!= 'h')
```

Whenever the response is 'q', then each of these tests is satisfied. Get rid of them; they do nothing you want. Instead, put a plain 'else' after the last valid char test and print the "not a valid choice" prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have something like,

```
 if (response.charAt(0)== 'w') 
 {
   ...
 }
 else if(response.charAt(0)== 'h')
 {
   ...
 }
 else if(response.charAt(0)== 'q')
 {
   System.exit(0);
 }
 else
 {
      System.out.println("That is not a valid choice try again");
                response = stdIn.next();

 }
```

Comment: try it without `else if (response.charAt(0)!= 'w')` or `else if (response.charAt(0)!= 'h')` in code.

Answer (score 0):

try

else if (response.charAt(0).contains('q'))